# print string buffer from file contents

Tags: ocaml

I want to print the contents of a file. I tried to use a string buffer:

```
let ch = open_in "myfile.txt" in
let buf = Buffer.create 1024 in
(try Buffer.add_channel buf ch max_int with _ -> ());
close_in ch;

let string = Buffer.contents buf
print_endline string
```

this just gives me a syntax error.

How can I do this?

Comment: For instance here you seem to not care at all about the answers you get. If you want people to spend time to answer to your questions, you need to make some effort, otherwise they won't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the right channel length:

```
let ic = open_in "foo" in
let len = in_channel_length ic in
let buf = Buffer.create len in
Buffer.add_channel bif ic len;
let str = Buffer.contents b in
print_endline str
```

Answer (score 0):

The only syntax error I see is a missing `in` after `let string = Buffer.contents buf`.

The purpose of `Buffer.add_channel` is to add exactly the given number of characters from the given channel to the buffer. Unless your file `"myfile.txt"` is exceptionally large, the buffer will be empty when you print it out.

In fact on my system (a 64-bit system), `max_int` is so large that `Buffer.add_channel` doesn't even try to read that much data. It raises an `Invalid_argument` exception.